# Map reverse-history-search function in bash to a shortcut other than CTRL+R

Tags: bash, unix, putty, remapping, command-history

I'm using Putty Connection Manager which captures CTRL-R key before it can get to my bash shell.

So I was wondering if it is possible to map the reverse-history-search to another shortcut key.  Such as CTRL-W or maybe even F1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. The **READLINE** section of the `bash(1)` man page tells you what you need to do and how you need to do it. In short, modify `~/.inputrc` and bind `reverse-search-history` to something else.

Comment: For an example of this, binding to PgUp/PgDn in this case, check out this [reverse history search answer](https://serverfault.com/a/173118/751).